# ReactJS onClick function called twice

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

When the user clicks the ***login*** button the user must get a proper alert box as login successful or unsuccessful. On clicking the button useDetails() function is triggered. In the frontend, the user can either input email or mobile and password is mandatory but onClick triggers the function 2 times and as a result, 2 times alert box is displayed ie the else part is executed everytime

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Card, CardTitle, Row, Col } from 'reactstrap'
import firebase from "../firebase";


function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

    function useDetails() {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .get().then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    // console.log(doc.data().Mobile);
                    var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(doc.data().Password, 'secret key 123');
                    var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                    var fname = doc.data().Full_name;
                    if (email === '' && mobile === doc.data().Mobile) {
                        if (password === plaintext) {
                            alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
                        }
                        else { alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials.."); }
                    }
                    else if (mobile === '' && email === doc.data().E_mail) {
                        if (password === plaintext) {
                            alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
                        }
                        else { alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials.."); }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("For a successful login either enter Mobile no. or enter Email id and password is mandatory");

                    }
                })
            });

        setEmail('');
        setMobile('');
        setPassword('');
    }
    const [passwordType, setPasswordType] = useState('password');
    const [passwordToggleText, setPasswordToggleText] = useState('Show');
    const passwordToggle = () => {
        if (passwordType === "password") {
            setPasswordType('text')
            setPasswordToggleText('Hide')
        }
        else {
            setPasswordType('password')
            setPasswordToggleText('Show')
        }
    }
    return (
        <Form className="form col-12" >
            <Row>
                <Card body >
                    <CardTitle><h4><b>Log In</b></h4></CardTitle>
                    <FormGroup>
                        <Row>
                            <Col><Label className="label ml-3">Mobile</Label></Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Row>
                            <Col xs="3" className="ml-3">
                                <Input type="code" placeholder="+91" readOnly />
                            </Col>
                            <Col xs="8">
                                <Input type="text" placeholder="Mobile" value={mobile} onChange={e => setMobile(e.target.value)} />
                            </Col>
                        </Row>
                        <Col className="separator mt-4 text-muted"> O R </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Label className="label">Email</Label>
                            <Input type="email" placeholder="Email" value={email} onChange={e => setEmail(e.target.value)} />
                        </Col>
                        <Col className="separator mt-4 text-muted"> A N D </Col>
                        <Col>
                            <Label className="label">Password</Label>
                            <Input type={passwordType} placeholder="Password" value={password} onChange={e => setPassword(e.target.value)} />
                            <span className="togglePassword" onClick={passwordToggle}><b>{passwordToggleText}</b></span>
                        </Col>
                    </FormGroup>

                    <Button color="primary" size="lg" block onClick={useDetails}>Log In</Button>
                </Card>
            </Row>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default Login
```

above code is the complete sample and the below code is the part I am facing problem in

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Card, CardTitle, Row, Col }from 'reactstrap'
import firebase from "../firebase";


function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

    function useDetails() {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .get().then((snapshot) => {
                snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {
                    // console.log(doc.data().Mobile);
                    var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(doc.data().Password, 'secret key 123');
                    var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                    var fname = doc.data().Full_name;
                    if (email === '' && mobile === doc.data().Mobile) {
                        if (password === plaintext) {
                            alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
                        }
                        else { alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials.."); }
                    }
                    else if (mobile === '' && email === doc.data().E_mail) {
                        if (password === plaintext) {
                            alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
                        }
                        else { alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials.."); }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("For a successful login either enter Mobile no. or enter Email id and password is mandatory");

                    }
                })
            });

        setEmail('');
        setMobile('');
        setPassword('');
    }

    return (
        <Form className="form col-12" >
            <Row>
                <Card body >
                    <CardTitle><h4><b>Log In</b></h4></CardTitle>
                    <Button color="primary" size="lg" block onClick={useDetails}>Log In</Button>
                </Card>
            </Row>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default Login
```

On every button click **else part** is executed even-if other **if and else-if parts** gets executed
[This is the link for the Website.](https://chat-with.netlify.app/) then click on the login button

> Email : rijusaha1234@gmail.com
>   Password : Mypassword1#

Comment: <Button color="primary" size="lg" block onClick={useDetails}>Log In</Button> Change this to ()=> useDetails()

Comment: <Button color="primary" size="lg" block onClick={() => useDetails()}>Log In</Button>
I have tried this and it is showing an error in the app as 
"  React Hook "useDetails" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks"

Comment: Change the name of the function and use a a lambda in the onClick.

Comment: Problem persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are retrieving all users via `firebase.firestore().collection("users").get()`. In your case it is two users. So at least for one of them "else" part is executed, that is why you see double alert.

```js
    function useDetails() {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .get().then((snapshot) => {
                const user = snapshot.docs.find(doc => (email === '' && mobile === doc.data().Mobile) || (mobile === '' && email === doc.data().E_mail));
                if (!user) {
                    // Matching user not found
                    alert("For a successful login either enter Mobile no. or enter Email id and password is mandatory");
                    return;
                }
                var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.data().Password, 'secret key 123');
                var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                if (password !== plaintext) {
                     alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials..");
                     return;
                }
                var fname = user.data().Full_name;
                alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
            });

        setEmail('');
        setMobile('');
        setPassword('');
    }
```

Comment: @Priyomsaha please take a look at added code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the arrow funtion instead of normal at `function useDetails()` your function will be as
`const useDetails =()=>{...}`
and your login button will looks like 
`<Button color="primary" size="lg" block onClick={() => useDetails()}>Log In</Button>`

Comment: try after commenting the setEmail(); setMobile();setPassword(). I think it is due to this and use the preventDefault inside your function useDetails

Answer (score 1):

Your forEach loop return two record from firebase server, so your code execute twice, So please verify on firebase result. 'snapshot.docs.forEach((doc) => {})' verify this.

Anyhow, I just change forEach loop to for loop to avoid further execution if you get condition true or false.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import { Form, FormGroup, Label, Input, Button, Card, CardTitle, Row, Col }from 'reactstrap'
import firebase from "../firebase";


function Login() {
    const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
    const [mobile, setMobile] = useState('');
    const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
    var CryptoJS = require("crypto-js");

    function useDetails() {
        firebase
            .firestore()
            .collection("users")
            .get().then((snapshot) => {

             for(let x=0; x<snapshot.length; x++){
let doc = snapshot[x];

                    // console.log(doc.data().Mobile);
                    var bytes = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(doc.data().Password, 'secret key 123');
                    var plaintext = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
                    var fname = doc.data().Full_name;
                    if (email === '' && mobile === doc.data().Mobile) {
                        if (password === plaintext) {
                            alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
break;
                        }
                        else { alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials.."); 
break;
}
                    }
                    else if (mobile === '' && email === doc.data().E_mail) {
                        if (password === plaintext) {
                            alert("Successfully logged in as : " + fname);
break;
                        }
                        else { alert("Wrong 1 or more credentials..");
break;
 }
                    }
                    else {
                        alert("For a successful login either enter Mobile no. or enter Email id and password is mandatory");
break;

                    }
            });

        setEmail('');
        setMobile('');
        setPassword('');
    }

    return (
        <Form className="form col-12" >
            <Row>
                <Card body >
                    <CardTitle><h4><b>Log In</b></h4></CardTitle>
                    <Button color="primary" size="lg" block onClick={useDetails}>Log In</Button>
                </Card>
            </Row>
        </Form>
    )
}

export default Login
```

Answer (score 0):

In `index.js` file, find the code below and remove `<React.StrictMode> .. </React.StrictMode>` tags.

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

After removing  tag :

```
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```